# Easy to set up 2-factor auth server? (SecureID looks scary to set up)

Tags: vpn

I want to use two factor auth for my vpn users. You know, the secureid kind of thing where they have a changing number from a keyfob to enter.

I got the free demo kit from secureid and... scary looking! It looked really involved to set up and evaluate.

I am hoping (dreaming?) of a really simple server that can act as a RADIUS server or such (so my juniper screenOS box can use it), that installs in a few minutes and is easy to test.

Does such exist?

Thank you for any thoughts on the subject!

P.S. I see the thread: [Alternatives to RSA SecurID?](https://serverfault.com/questions/23284/alternatives-to-rsa-securid)  which is great.

If this thread could focus on ease of install and set up that would be great.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yubikey? I haven't tried to install it in conjunction with a RADIUS server, but the token is much easier on end user.

There are some instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/yubico-pam/wiki/YubikeyAndRadiusViaPAM

Answer (score 1):

I can't really offer you a suggestion for an *easy* to use two factor ID tool, but I can confirm that RSA's SecurID is non-trivial.  It has the feel of a legacy application, with an interface and architecture that is not at all intuitive.

Having setup and maintained RSA's ACE Server/Authentication Manager before, I would definitely investigate alternatives very thoroughly before I would set it up again.

Answer (score 0):

[Mobile-OTP](http://motp.sourceforge.net/) + [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/) or [XTRadius](http://xtradius.sourceforge.net/).  easy and free clients and servers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out challenge/response token systems like Alladin/SecureComputing [Safeword](http://www.aladdin.com/SafeWord/default.aspx). Very easy to setup. I believe there are a couple of similar solutions out there, but I cannot recall the vendors at the moment.

Comment: any chance you can recall the others?

I am really looking to understand the landscape...